# Centos warewulf cluster with openmpi

Tags: linux, centos

I have setup a warewulf cluster on centos 7 and i have installed openmpi-x86_64-1.10.0-10.el7, additionally i also installed mpich. Wen i run mpirun with openmpi it results in the error below, the same with mpich works perfectly. Changing the n0000 to the cluster master also works, but it is not running in the node.

```
mpirun -n 1 -host n0000 echo $HOSTNAME
[n0000.cluster:01719] [[24772,0],1] tcp_peer_send_blocking: send() to socket 9 failed: Broken pipe (32)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons.
This usually is caused by:

* not finding the required libraries and/or binaries on
  one or more nodes. Please check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  settings, or configure OMPI with --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default

* lack of authority to execute on one or more specified nodes.
  Please verify your allocation and authorities.

* the inability to write startup files into /tmp (--tmpdir/orte_tmpdir_base).
  Please check with your sys admin to determine the correct location to use.

*  compilation of the orted with dynamic libraries when static are required
  (e.g., on Cray). Please check your configure cmd line and consider using
  one of the contrib/platform definitions for your system type.

* an inability to create a connection back to mpirun due to a
  lack of common network interfaces and/or no route found between
  them. Please check network connectivity (including firewalls
  and network routing requirements).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Bellow you can find the cluster and server ip addr outputs. I have also took a look at https://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2015/09/27643.php where a similar problem is described, but i don't think i have interfaces in the same subnetwork.

```
Server:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:2e:ee:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 85746sec preferred_lft 85746sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe2e:eec2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:76:b9:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.1.1/24 brd 10.1.1.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe76:b9e7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_ft forever


Node:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/24 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:57:46:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.1.10/24 brd 10.1.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe57:46ce/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like a firewall issue. Have you tried disabling firewall and/or are you sure the correct service is running on the remote machine?

Comment: I have a minimal install of centos, i don't think it has a firewall. iptables not installed and firewalls either.

Comment: What medium are you using to interconnect the nodes (Ethernet, fiber, etc)?  How many nodes do you have total?   What type of device are you using to terminate all of your connections?

Comment: I am using a host-only network of virtual box and both master and node are running on virtual machines.

Comment: Oh ok.  What type of network adapter are you using in virtual box on the node and master?  Do you know if both machines can communicate over tcp/ip via ping or any other network protocols?

Comment: Scratch that I see you are using host only

Comment: Can the machines see each other?

Comment: Yes, they can see each other. I can ssh passwordless. And if mpich is used instead, the job gets done.

Comment: Interestingly, if i execute the command on the node, it will run with no problem. It is only if the master node is executing the command that the problem arises. How can i solve or debug this? Where can i get more information?

Comment: Ok, if i disable enp0s3, the network being used for internet, the mpirun can be executed in the master. So i believe the problem should be similar to the one described in https://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2015/09/27643.php .

Answer (score 0):

Where did you install the OpenFOAM ?

Did you install it on /opt/ or /home/username/OpenFOAM ?

If you did the first one, the compute node can't find your top location(/opt/)

Comment: just wondering, does message passing really depend on fluid dynamics library?  Looks to me that each node is instructed to simply `echo $HOSTNAME`?